# using google analytics in laravel project

Tags: google-analytics, laravel-5.3

hey guys i'm trying to use google analytics in my project but i always get an error : `Argument 1 passed to Spatie\LaravelAnalytics\LaravelAnalytics::__construct() must be an instance of Spatie\LaravelAnalytics\GoogleApiHelper, none given`
actually i don't know how to deal with that error as it's my first time to use it .
that's simply the code i've written :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\ProductTrans;
use App\Service;
use Spatie\LaravelAnalytics\LaravelAnalytics;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    //
    public function getIndex() {
        $services = Service::get();
        $products = Product::get();
        $analyticsData =new LaravelAnalytics();
        $analyticsData->getVisitorsAndPageViews();
        dd($analyticsData);

        return view('admin.pages.home',compact('services','products'));
    }
```

so can anyone help me ?

Comment: Not sure what version you're using, but the latest one comes with a Facade you can use (e.g. `Analytics::getVisitorsAndPageViews()`)

Comment: thanks for reply but whenever i summon it , it gets me different files than what's shown on the package @apokryfos